# Who is this member of the Catholic Church?

Tags: catholicism, tradition, latin, humanity

I was wondering who this man is, in the Catholic church:

[image]

I am wondering his position therein more so than his name. *I saw him in a dream moments ago—I am not Catholic, I am Apostolic Pentecostal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This person is a deacon, which can be discerned from the fact that he is wearing the [dalmatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalmatic), the deacon’s traditional vestment. (Based on the background and the logo of the [Vatican Television Center](http://www.vatican.va/news_services/television/index.htm), this appears to be in St. Peter’s Basilica; I suspect this deacon is proclaiming the Gospel, or—if this was taken at the Easter Vigil—the Easter Proclamation or [*Exsultet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exsultet).)

Comment: Thank you, I had a feeling he was a deacon. Yes, this is from the easter service, that I got this, when this man "infamously" sung the, I assume traditional, song that has the lyrics: "Flammas eius lúcifer matutínus invéniat..."

Comment: Yes, the text you are referring to is the Exsultet. (Don’t be put off by the word “lucifer”: in Latin, “lucifer matutinus”—literally “the morning light-bearer”—means the Morning Star; i.e., the planet Venus, though in this case, it is referring to the risen Jesus Christ who is symbolized by the Easter Candle.)

Comment: The full phrase is, ”Flammas eius lucifer matutinus inveniat: / ille, inquam, lucifer, qui nescit occasum, /Christus Fílius tuus,” which means “May the Morning Star find its [i.e., the Easter Candle’s] flames: this Morning Star, I say, that does not know setting, Jesus Christ your Son.” (Or said in more ordinary language, “May the candle still be lit by the time the Morning Star rises; I am referring to the Morning Star that never sets, namely, Jesus Christ your Son.”)

Comment: Thank you, I know what the word Lucifer means. I don't know this man's heart. Do I think there are some catholics who sing it to the chief of demons? yes, just as there would be some protestants, but this man, I know not, but I know how it can be interpreted. Thank you in any case. I have been thinking about learning latin, to learn Greek from the 1600's to make a lexicon in concordance with the A.K.J.V., to prevent the modern perverted definitions of Koine words from scholars actually.

Comment: @MatthewTScarbrough, absolutely not. Its context within the Easter Vigil makes it perfectly clear that the reference is Jesus Christ. Anyway, the Exsultet is usually sung in translation.